# Как растянуть div с position: absolute; на всю высоту body

Tags: html, css

перекопал весь интернет, ответа не нашел
цель такая:
нужно сделать фон с помощью svg вставок
каждая из них позиционирована относительно родительского блока
родительский блок имеет z-index -99
и position absolute
но растянуть получается его только на высоту окна браузера
и как итог div не растягивается на весь body
есть ли какое либо решение?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить, что значит `на весь экран браузера` `а не получается на весь body` чем отличаются эти термины в вашем понятии ?

Comment: В разных браузерах где то надо растянуть html а где то body на 100% высоты и потому не пориться написать в css так: html,body height 100%  и нужный элемент так же сделать в  эту высоту

Comment: Привет! Чувствую себя экстрасенсом с вопросом без кода, честно так сложно решать задачу, вот решение могу предложить, но оно может не помочь

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -99;
}